# Using a .Zap eraser file in html

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and my client wants what he refers to as a "Eraser file" to be on the top section of the site. Here is a example website that uses this feature http://flashpoint.gatech.edu/
How can I use this file and implement it in html? I have searched for eraser and zap file answers, but could not find anything on them.

Comment: Sounds entirely made up. Have you considered asking the client to clarify what they are referring to and why they need it?

Comment: This question could be click bait anyway. The linked site has some dodgy redirects to an IP address and nothing related to the question

Comment: What do you want to implement? The functionality which allows you to erase the screen with your mouse cursor?

Comment: yes @Badacadabra

Comment: @ZacharyCheshire OK, so... See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy because it is actually a jQuery plugin...

*(I did not find any viable CDN for that library, so I cannot give you the live example in a JSFiddle. Please download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boblemarin/jQuery.eraser/master/jquery.eraser.js) in a file called "eraser.js" and put it in the same directory as this HTML file. You should be able to erase the Stack Overflow logo.)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Eraser</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="eraser.js"></script>
  <script>$('img').eraser();</script>
</body>
</html>
```